# can't install or update any program, dpkg: error

Tags: upgrade, updates, dpkg

every time I try to install or update anything it gives this error

```
    dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

open ternimal and type these one by one

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get --fix-missing install

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

this should fix it.

[Source](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/55616)

Answer (score 0):

The `available` database can be empty with very little harm, it just needs to exist. Simply create it as an empty file with

```
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/available
```